# How do I pivot and join 3 different tables by a ID column using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Say I want to join these 3 dataframes with dplyr. How do I do it? I know I should use some combination of **pivots** and **joins**, but I can't figure out how to get it right.

My goal is to have the df something like this:

```r
mpg_deciles mean_mpg mean_price production coefficient
1           13.5     12990      Foreign    12990
2           16       10874      Domestic   10874.8571428572
```

Heres the data

```r
library(dplyr)

a <- tibble::tribble(
  ~mpg_deciles,        ~mean_mpg,
  1L,             13.5,
  2L,               16,
  3L,            17.75,
  4L,           18.625,
  5L, 19.7142857142857)


 b <- tibble::tribble(
    ~coeff_foreign, ~mpg_deciles,  ~mean_p_foreign,  ~foreign,
    12990,            2,            12990, "Foreign",
    -2147.49999999997,            3,          10842.5, "Foreign",
    -7180.99999999996,            4, 5809.00000000003, "Foreign",
    -6777.49999999999,            6,           6212.5, "Foreign",
    -6435.3333333333,            7, 6554.66666666669, "Foreign")
  
  
c <- tibble::tribble(
    ~coeff_domestic, ~mpg_deciles, ~mean_p_domestic,   ~foreign,
    10874.8571428572,           1L, 10874.8571428572, "Domestic",
    -3697.73214285716,           2L,         7177.125, "Domestic",
    -6031.19047619049,           3L, 4843.66666666666, "Domestic",
    -6365.35714285716,           4L,           4509.5, "Domestic",
    -4650.42857142859,           5L, 6224.42857142857, "Domestic")
```

Comment: why does the output connect the mpg_deciles = 1 row of a with the mpg_deciles = 2  row of b, and mpg_deciles = 2 row of a with mpg_deciles = 1 of c?

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pre-process `b` and `c` and then use a `left_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)

a %>% 
  left_join(
    bind_rows(
      b %>% 
        rename(coefficient = coeff_foreign, mean_price = mean_p_foreign, production = foreign),
      c %>%     
        rename(coefficient = coeff_domestic, mean_price = mean_p_domestic, production = foreign)
      ),
    by = "mpg_deciles"
  )
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  mpg_deciles mean_mpg coefficient mean_price production
        <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>     
1           1     13.5      10875.     10875. Domestic  
2           2     16        12990      12990  Foreign   
3           2     16        -3698.      7177. Domestic  
4           3     17.8      -2147.     10842. Foreign   
5           3     17.8      -6031.      4844. Domestic  
6           4     18.6      -7181.      5809. Foreign   
7           4     18.6      -6365.      4510. Domestic  
8           5     19.7      -4650.      6224. Domestic
```

The pre-processing changes the `coeff_foreign` and `coeff_domestic` (same for `mean_p_`) columns into columns of the same name. If now the two data.frames are appended to each other, all values with the same column names go into the respective (same) columns. Without this pre-processing the columns with different names (e.g. `coeff_foreign` and `coeff_domestic`) would not end in the same column, but two columns are created (`coeff_foreign` and `coeff_domestic`) where the values are stored. In this case `left_join` would not achieve the desired result.

Comment: Thank you, that does it. Of course you have to rename the column names to match before joining. Do you mind writing a sentence or two on the intuition for using bind_rows within *_join? I think it might be helful to others. My feeling is that this should work without this after renaming the columns, but it does not. Don't see why though.

Comment: @TomasR I tried to clarify the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Updated version: Thanks to @Martin Gal input:

We could use a nested `left_join`:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(a, b, by='mpg_deciles') %>%
  left_join(., c, by='mpg_deciles') %>% 
  select(-starts_with("foreign")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c("mpg_deciles", "mean_mpg"), names_pattern = "(coeff|mean_p)_(.*)", names_to = c(".value", "production"), values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

```
  mpg_deciles mean_mpg production  coeff mean_p
        <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
1           1     13.5 domestic   10875. 10875.
2           2     16   foreign    12990  12990 
3           2     16   domestic   -3698.  7177.
4           3     17.8 foreign    -2147. 10842.
5           3     17.8 domestic   -6031.  4844.
6           4     18.6 foreign    -7181.  5809.
7           4     18.6 domestic   -6365.  4510.
8           5     19.7 domestic   -4650.  6224.
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not give the desired result. For example, the values "Foreign" and "Domestic should be in the same column named "production",

Comment: Hey @TarJae. I think your answer could be improved, by deselecting those `foreign.x` and `foreign.y` columns and bringing in to a _long_ format: just pipe `select(-starts_with("foreign")) %>% pivot_longer(-c("mpg_deciles", "mean_mpg"), names_pattern = "(coeff|mean_p)_(.*)", names_to = c(".value", "production"), values_drop_na = TRUE)`. :)